# Is there anyway to trace all classes and interfaces used or referenced in a C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, trace

I have a huge cryptography solution that has way more than what we need. I need some way of debugging the program and keeping track of each class that was called after running my main() method. Any tips? Right now I'm attepting to hold down F11 and go through all the classes that opened up one by one and manually check what was called. Not what I want to do. I'm stripping out everything that wasn't needed afterwards for memory leak, performance, and size reasons. It's open source code. Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Code which is not executed cannot be the source of a memory leak. Whether it affects performance depends on the platform; if C# is like Java in this respect, then classes which are not loaded take no run-time resources. Size of a distribution, on the other hand, is a valid reason to strip unused code.

Answer (score 1):

[Dottrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/documentation/) should do the trick for you. It has a really handy way of profiling any running .NET code and spitting out an [easy-to-consume report](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/index.html). I highly recommend the tool (it's also good for what it's designed for - performance & memory profiling). This sounds like an ad, but I have nothing to do with the company. I just love the app.

Comment: I would suggest that any tracing program will suffice. This is a particularly good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.NET Reflector tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). Also this is a built-in feature in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Reflector will only help explore static dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing has always been the default showcase for [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

PostSharp: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net

Comment: My mind also went to AOP when I first read this, but I would bet that actually implementing an aspect in this case (just to gather data once and then throw away the aspect & a bunch of code) is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: That depends on how bad your pain with F11 is... ;-)